# Mirroring the Y axis in SFML

Tags: c++, graph, rendering, coordinate-systems, sfml

Hey so I'm integrating box2d and SFML, and box2D has the same odd, mirrored Y-axis coordinate system as SFML, meaning everything is rendered upside down. Is there some kind of function or short amount of code I can put that simply mirrors the window's render contents?

I'm thinking I can put something in sf::view to help with this...

**How can i easily flip the Y-axis easily, for rendering purposes, not effecting the bodies dimensions/locations?**

Comment: I think the problem with using an inverse view is that all the sprites will be rendered upside-down as well, not just inverted positions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is box2d but when I wanted to flip Y axis using openGL, I just applied negative scaling factor to projection matrix, like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

If you want to do it independent of openGL simply apply a sf::View with a negative x value.

Comment: where would i put this? could i somehow make a sf::view FlipAxis() function with it?

Comment: You must flip object that you render. I don't know how far you're with integrating these 2 projects, but every SFML::Drawable (and so on Text, Shape,...) has SetScale function. You could set negative factor here: Object.SetScale(1.0f,-1.0f). However if you're maintaining rendering youself through opengl, you can just set it as I mentioned above. Above won't work for SFML::Drawable only if you're using PreserveOpenGLStates, because it splits openGL to 2 states, one for you and one for SFML. This function is however missing since SFML 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your model uses a conventional coordinate system (positive y points up), and you need to translate that to the screen coordinate system (positive y points down).

When copying model/Box2D position data to any sf::Drawable, manually transform between the model and screen coordinate systems:

```
b2Vec2 position = body->GetPosition();

sprite.SetPosition( position.x, window.GetHeight() - position.y )
```

You can hide this in a wrapper class or function, but it needs to sit between the model and renderer as a pre-render transform.  I don't see a place to set that in SFML.

I think Box2D has the coordinate system you want; just set the gravity vector based on your model (0, -10) instead of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

> **How can i easily flip the Y-axis easily, for rendering purposes, not effecting the bodies dimensions/locations?**

By properly applying transforms. First, you can apply a transform that sets the window's bottom-left corner as the origin. Then, scale the *Y* axis by a factor of *-1* to flip it as the second transform.

For this, you can use [`sf::Transformable`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php) to specify each transformation individually (i.e., the setting of the origin and the scaling) and then – by calling [`sf::Transformable::getTransform()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a7f7c3f0bab3f162b13613904fbdbb9ad) – obtain an [`sf::Transform`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transform.php) object that corresponds to the composed transform.

Finally, when rendering the corresponding object, pass this transform object to the [`sf::RenderTarget::draw()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a12417a3bcc245c41d957b29583556f39) member function as its second argument. An `sf::Transform` object implicitly converts to a [`sf::RenderStates`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderStates.php) which is the second parameter type of the corresponding [`sf::RenderTarget::draw()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a12417a3bcc245c41d957b29583556f39) overload.

As an example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

auto main() -> int {
    auto const width = 300, height = 300;
    sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Transformation");
    win.setFramerateLimit(60);

    // create the composed transform object
    const sf::Transform transform = [height]{
        sf::Transformable transformation;
        transformation.setOrigin(0, height); // 1st transform
        transformation.setScale(1.f, -1.f);  // 2nd transform
        return transformation.getTransform();
    }();

    sf::RectangleShape rect({30, 30});

    while (win.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (win.pollEvent(event))
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                win.close();

        // update rectangle's position
        rect.move(0, 1);

        win.clear();

        rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        win.draw(rect); // no transformation applied

        rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        win.draw(rect, transform); // transformation applied

        win.display();
    }
}
```

There is a single `sf::RectangleShape` object that is rendered twice with different colors:

1. Blue: no transform was applied.
2. Red: the composed transform was applied.

They move in opposite directions as a result of flipping the *Y* axis.

[image: Transformation]

Note that the *object space* position coordinates remain the same. Both rendered rectangles correspond to the same object, i.e., there is just a single `sf::RectangleShape` object, `rect` – only the color is changed. The object space position is `rect.getPosition()`.

What is different for these two rendered rectangles is the *coordinate reference system*. Therefore, the *absolute space* position coordinates of these two rendered rectangles also differ.

You can use this approach in a *scene tree*. In such a tree, the transforms are applied in a top-down manner from the parents to their children, starting from the root. The net effect is that children's coordinates are relative to their parent's absolute position.